# Make Ctrl-Alt-T focus existing terminal window if there is no active process in it

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to focus (bring back to front) an existing terminal window if there is no running process in it (e.g. top). If there is no terminal window without a running process, a new window should be opened. Is that possible?

Edit: It's not a duplicate. The further going idea is the following:
I do not want to get a terminal where I can not execute a command right now because it's busy (a process is running in it, e.g top). So my wish was to get only a already opened terminal if there is no process in it.

Comment: Actually, this question has been asked before, so I copied this answer also to the other question. You will find other options there, all script based, though.

Comment: It indeed is a different question so I voted to open the question again. I will remove my answer here - it is in the other post where it is appropriate. I am not sure whether a script could query on the status of an open terminal window, whether it is idle or busy.